# How to catch exception in Java?

Tags: java, exception

I am getting following exception in my code and I want to catch the inner exception. Is it possible to catch that?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: error
some stack trace
some stack trace
some stack trace
! Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
some stack trace
some stack trace
some stack trace
```

Lets say I have following code.

```
function abc() {
  try{
    xyz()
  } catch (TimeoutException e) {
     do stuff
  }
}
```

xyz() function is generating that exception. Would catching the TimeoutException like this work?

Comment: It may...did you try run it?

Comment: I don't have a good way to test it

Comment: You say you are "getting following exception in my code" so you _do_ have a way to test it... just put that try-catch in your code that's getting the exception.

Comment: the stack trace is important.  Yes, you can catch it if there is a single method in the exception's stack trace that is yours before it is converted to a different exception

Comment: If you have control over `xyz()`, the cleanest solution would be to have it throw a plain `TimeoutException` instead of wrapping it inside a `RuntimeException` for cases that you need to handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it directly. You have to catch the outer exception, check its `getCause()` to see if it's what you want, and then either handle that cause or re-throw the top-level exception.

(You could also technically re-throw just the inner one, but I would strongly discourage that; the stack trace will be very confusing, and it'll be harder to debug -- especially a year from now, when you've forgotten that you did that.)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't catch a `RuntimeException` with `catch(TimeoutException e)`.

However, you could do

```
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
  Throwable cause = e.getCause(); 
}
```

to get the cause.

Comment: No one should write `catch (Exception e)`.

Comment: @VGR: What do you mean? Can you explain why?

Comment: One should only catch the exceptions that need to be caught.  `catch (Exception)` will catch things that should normally indicate programmer errors, like NullPointerException.  There is no proper way to recover from such an error;  such an exception should, in fact, cause the thread to halt, loudly and clearly, so the programmer is encouraged to fix that error.

Comment: The question is specifically about runtime and timeout exceptions. You are generalizing that to Exception for no good reason at all. Having said that: putting "throws Exception" into a method signature or a catch clause is bad practice, but sometimes inevitable nonetheless.

Comment: VGR: that really depends on context. Catching Exception on top level can be fine. Like in a rest endpoint where you want to log any error and return like 512 "internal error" for unexpected exceptions. Never say never.

Comment: @GhostCat: I see what you mean. Updated my answer.

Comment: @GhostCat: At the very top level, you even to catch the Throwable. Otherwise, I don't like seeing try/catch everywhere. This code is only to demonstrate how to get the cause.

Comment: Sure. But you might have a cascade of catch statements. Maybe there are good reasons to first catch Exception before catching Thriwable...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly catch a `RuntimeException` caused by a `TimeoutException`.

But you achieve it like this:

```
    try {
        xyz();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        if (e.getCause() instanceof TimeoutException) {
            // handle TimeoutException
            doStuff();
        } else {
            // rethrow all exceptions with other causes
            throw e;
        }
    }
```